# How does the lazy evaluation works in infinite prime list generator? HASKELL

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

```
primes :: [Int]
primes = sieve [2..]

sieve :: [Int] -> [Int]
sieve (n:ns) = n : sieve [n' | n' <- ns, mod n n' /= 0]
```

So I get this. This lines of code will generate me a infinite list of prime numbers but I am struggling to understand one thing that when I try to filter out all of multiples of 2 from an infinite list, which are also infinite in number, so how we are making the recursive call before filtering out the all multiples of 2. Cause as I am trying to generate a infinite list of all prime numbers so therefore all the multiples of 2 first needs to get removed before we go the next prime number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter`, like many things in Haskell, is lazy. It won't immediately evaluate its result either. Even if given a finite list, it'll just "remember" what it needs to do and only do so when forced. Let's see a few steps of evaluation. Here's your code

```
sieve :: [Int] -> [Int]
sieve (n:ns) = n : sieve [n' | n' <- ns, mod n' n /= 0]
```

(Note: The `n'` and `n` are backward in `mod` in your version; I've taken the liberty of correcting this)

And let's assume I've just done `print (sieve [2..])` (where `print` forces its argument fully for the purposes of printing).

Then we have

```
sieve [2..]
```

`sieve` is pattern matching on its argument, so we need the first element of our infinite argument. That is, we have to force the first element, to get

```
sieve (2 : [3..])
```

Now we have enough information to call `sieve` once. Let's substitute the left-hand side of our definition with the right-hand side. Note that `n` is `2` and `ns` is `[3..]`.

```
2 : sieve [n' | n' <- [3..], mod 2 n' /= 0]
```

We haven't forced the list comprehension at this point. It's still just a glorified filter. At this point, `print` has enough information to print out the `2`. But now we need the next element of our list, since we're going to print them all out. So we need to evaluate `sieve` far enough to get the next element. `sieve`, in turn, pattern matches on its argument, so we need the first element of the list comprehension. Ultimately we'll get

```
-- Grab the first possible value of n'
2 : sieve [n' | n' <- 3 : [4..], mod n' 2 /= 0]
-- Oh look! `mod 3 2 /= 0` is true! We can include this!
2 : sieve (3 : [n' | n' <- [4..], mod n' 2 /= 0])
```

Now `sieve` evaluates, with `n` equal to `3` and `ns` equal to... that whole list comprehension mess. I'm going to leave it as `ns` for a minute here, just to make it a bit easier to read.

```
2 : 3 : sieve [n' | n' <- ns, mod n' 3 /= 0]
```

But as I said, `ns` is *really* that whole list comprehension, so this is really

```
2 : 3 : sieve [n' | n' <- [n' | n' <- [4..], mod n' 2 /= 0], mod n' 3 /= 0]
```

Okay, now let's go through one more step, just to see what it looks like to *skip* a value. Same rules as before: we need another value, so `sieve` needs to produce something, but it needs the first element of its argument in order to pattern match. So we try to force an element out of the list comprehension.

```
-- Original value (same as above)
2 : 3 : sieve [n' | n' <- [n' | n' <- [4..], mod n' 2 /= 0], mod n' 3 /= 0]
-- Now let's try to get a value from the list comprehension
2 : 3 : sieve [n' | n' <- [n' | n' <- 4 : [5..], mod n' 2 /= 0], mod n' 3 /= 0]
-- Uh-oh! `mod 4 2 /= 0` is false; throw this value away!
2 : 3 : sieve [n' | n' <- [n' | n' <- [5..], mod n' 2 /= 0], mod n' 3 /= 0]
-- I still need a value; keep going
2 : 3 : sieve [n' | n' <- [n' | n' <- 5 : [6..], mod n' 2 /= 0], mod n' 3 /= 0]
-- `mod 5 2 /= 0` is true, so the inner comprehension succeeds.
2 : 3 : sieve [n' | n' <- (5 : [n' | n' <- [6..], mod n' 2 /= 0]), mod n' 3 /= 0]
-- `mod 5 3 /= 0` is true, so the outer one succeeds.
2 : 3 : sieve (5 : [n' | n' <- [n' | n' <- [6..], mod n' 2 /= 0], mod n' 3 /= 0])
```

Now `sieve` has enough information to continue, so it produces the value of `5` per its definition and then calls itself with a new argument which is going to consist of *three* nested list comprehensions. The comprehensions will just keep growing.

Now in reality, any Haskell implementation worth its salt is going to optimize that, so you'll probably end up with one big list comprehension that has several conditions. But that's an optimization trick, not a part of the non-strict semantics per se.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you recommend some books where I can learn more about the lazy evaluation process, in particular, and other features of functional languages in general? I am currently learning Haskell and want to ensure my understanding of these concepts is absolutely clear.

Comment: @RifatAhmed I'm not sure what tutorial you're using to learn Haskell, but hands-down the best one out there is Learn You A Haskell (http://learnyouahaskell.com/), which is available online for free.

Answer (score 0):

> so therefore all the multiples of 2 first needs to get removed before we go the next prime number?

**No**, the filtering is lazy as well. Indeed, the filter operation, which is what your list comprehension does, is implemented as:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter p = go
  where go [] = []
        go (x:xs) | p x = x : go xs
                  | otherwise = go xs
```

So that will act as a generator as well: you can always ask the next item, and it will return the next item that is not dividable by two, three, five, etc.

The list comprehension thus does *not* eagerly first filters out all items. It passes a generator that will work with the filtered items. This thus means that if we pass it an infinite list [2, 3, 4, ...]`, it will return` 2` as first item, and recurse on a list of all items not dividable by two. But that list is lazy as well. If we then ask for the next item, it will return three, and we recurse on a generator that takes as input another generator and will return items divided by three.